# How to get the Three.Camera reference?

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am trying to render a `<a-camera>` output to a canvas,
i've set up a canvas in my assets:

```
<canvas id="canvasnd" crossorigin="anonymous"></canvas>
```

I've got a camera:

```
<a-entity id="ndcam" camera look-controls position="2 1.6 -1" rotation="0 90 
 0"></a-entity>
```

And when i try to render the camera output like this:

```
  var cameraElement = document.querySelector("#ndcam");
  var camera = cameraElement.getAttribute("camera");
  var sceneEl = this.el;
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvasnd
  });

  function render() {
    renderer.render(sceneEl, camera);
  }
  render();
```

I get the `camera is not an instance of three.js camera` error. 
The code is on the a-scene, hence the `sceneEl = this.el;`.

I tried getting the `camera.el`, `camera.parentNode`, `sceneEl.systems.camera`, `sceneEl.systems.camera.activeCameraEl`, but i have really no idea how to get a valid three.camera reference.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960058/how-to-listen-to-cameras-world-position-in-a-frame), but the event never fires.
Live [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/cjjw1d8a/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an reference to the `a-scene` element, you can just call it with a direct reference.

```
let sceneEl = ...;    
let camera = sceneEl.camera;
```

The camera is an component and can either reside in an `a-entity` or an `a-camera` (exclusively to the API). If the element is an A-Frame primitive, it should have a object which stores all components. A simple way to query for a camera could be:

```
let cameraEl = document.querySelector('a-entity[camera]')
if (!cameraEl) {
    cameraEl = document.querySelector('a-camera');
}
let camera = cameraEl.components.camera.camera;
```

Where the first camera reference is the component and the second an instance of `THREE.Camera`.